# How can I map this output in Retrofit?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm new in Retrofit and I get the following JSON from my server:

```
    {
     "2": {
        "entity_id": "2",
        "website_id": "1",
        "email": "ddd@gmail.xx",
        "group_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2013-08-05 13:13:29",
        "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
        "prefix": null,
        "firstname": "dennis",
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": "Napf",
        "suffix": null,
        "taxvat": null,
        "created_in": "Admin"
     },
     "3": {
        "entity_id": "3",
        "website_id": "1",
        "email": "pit@gmail.xx",
        "group_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2013-08-14 17:48:28",
        "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
        "prefix": null,
        "firstname": "pit",
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": "doe",
        "suffix": null,
        "taxvat": null,
        "created_in": "Admin"
     },
     "4": {
        "entity_id": "4",
        "website_id": "1",
        "email": "xxxx@ttt.com`enter code here`",
        "group_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2013-08-14 17:49:32",
        "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
        "prefix": null,
        "firstname": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
        "suffix": null,
        "taxvat": null,
        "created_in": "Admin"
      }
    }
```

I have no idea haw to map this. The object name is missing (here customer). Instead I get the customer's id. In the debugger I can see this results is a `LinkedTreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bad json, change it as follow

```
{
  "info": {
  [ 
 {
    "entity_id": "2",
    "website_id": "1",
    "email": "ddd@gmail.xx",
    "group_id": "1",
    "created_at": "2013-08-05 13:13:29",
    "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
    "prefix": null,
    "firstname": "dennis",
    "middlename": null,
    "lastname": "Napf",
    "suffix": null,
    "taxvat": null,
    "created_in": "Admin"
 },{
    "entity_id": "3",
    "website_id": "1",
    "email": "pit@gmail.xx",
    "group_id": "1",
    "created_at": "2013-08-14 17:48:28",
    "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
    "prefix": null,
    "firstname": "pit",
    "middlename": null,
    "lastname": "doe",
    "suffix": null,
    "taxvat": null,
    "created_in": "Admin"
 },{
    "entity_id": "4",
    "website_id": "1",
    "email": "xxxx@ttt.com`enter code here`",
    "group_id": "1",
    "created_at": "2013-08-14 17:49:32",
    "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
    "prefix": null,
    "firstname": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
    "middlename": null,
    "lastname": "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
    "suffix": null,
    "taxvat": null,
    "created_in": "Admin"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

about parsing use this [tutorial](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/) may help you